# Compare strings with !== in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I want to compare two strings introduced by user with prompt.

If I do 
(bar == "yes" || bar == "no")

it works correctly, but if I use !==

(bar !== "yes" || bar !== "no")

the program return always the

alert("The second value must be \'yes\' or \'no\'");

even when I introduce yes or no as a second value.

```
do{
    var values = window.prompt("Introduce a title, and \'yes\' o \'no\' separted with a comma.");
    var longValues = values.length;
    var comma = values.indexOf(",");
    var title = values.substr(0,comma);
    var bar = values.substr(comma+1,longValues);
    var longTitle = title.length;

  if (longTitle <3 || longTitle >30){
     alert("The title must be greater than 3 characters and less than 30 characters");
 }
 else if (bar !== "yes" || bar !== "no"){
    alert("The second value must be \'yes\' or \'no\'");
}
 else{
     alert("Correct!");
 }
}while((longTitle <3 || longTitle >30) && (bar !=="yes" || bar !=="no"))
```

Comment: Logically, that is entirely correct. Either one – *not* "yes' or *not* "no" – is always going to be true (and optionally both).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition needs to be AND instead of OR. Change

```
if (bar !== "yes" || bar !== "no")
```

to

```
if (bar !== "yes" && bar !== "no")
```

If you are using OR, you are asking your code if `bar` is not equal to `yes` or `bar` is not equal to `no`. If value of `bar` is `yes`, then first condition is `false`, but second condition is `true`, so the result is `true`. The same is also valid if `bar` is `no` - in that case first condition gives `true`, second condition `false`, so the result is also `true`.

What you want instead is to execute code when `bar` is not `yes` and also when `bar` is not `no`.